# ruby on rails mysql fulltext relevance score in array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, match

I have a (mysql-) table with fulltext indexes for two columns --> firstname, middlename.

When I use SQl

```
SELECT firstname, middlename, MATCH (firstname, middlename) as score AGAINST ('Peter') FROM database.tbl_names where MATCH (firstname, middlename) AGAINST ('Peter')
```

I get 3 Columns --> firstname, middlename and score.

But when I try it with ruby like

```
TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter')as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20)
```

I get only an array with two "columns" but without the "match-column"

```
<TblName firstname: "Peter", middlename: "">
```

I searched an tried the whole sunday and didn't find a solution with the "match-column" in the array.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks ahead!!!

Comment: What happens if you call 

TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter')as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20).first.score ?

Comment: result is only: => 8.448237419128418

Comment: Is that not the score you are looking for? Have a look a the output from TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter')as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20).first.attributes

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 version :

```
Model.select("*, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('keyword') AS score").where("MATCH(title) AGAINST('keyword')").reorder("score DESC").first.score
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails won't show the "score" property in the returned array (as it isn't initialised in the model). You have to use the attributes call to find it.

Try:

```
TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter') as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20).first.score
```

And see if you can get the score that way.

You can also get a list of the attributes for that record (including the score) by using:

```
TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter') as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20).first.attributes
```

If you want to see the attributes for all the records at once, something like this will do it:

```
TblName.find(:all, :select => "firstname, middlename, match(firstname, middlename) against ('Peter') as score", :order => 'score desc', :conditions => ['match(firstname, middlename) against (?)', 'Peter'], :limit => 20).collect!(&:attributes)
```

Comment: same result as above. Only => 8.448237419128418 but not 3 columns.

Comment: Using the attributes method above is the only way to see the returned score. This is because it isn't an attribute that Rails creates for the table as it isn't a column it can see. What you are experiencing is the correct behaviour for Rails and there is no way to make it appear in what Rails returns (unless, of course, you use pure SQL).

Comment: It works!! But only with one result (first). Is there a posibility to use not "first" so there will be shown all results?

Comment: Have added a method to the answer

Comment: You made my day!!!!! Same Result as pure SQL, Thanks a lot! In swabian german we would say "den ka mr schigga":-). Swabia is a region with own dialect in south west germany, the home of Porsche, Mercedes etc. and it's one of the highest compliments you can make:-))))

Comment: I'll copy that phrase down in case I need to flatter someone! Happy to help :) would you mind accepting this answer?